# Could my closed question be re-opened? I have edited it

Tags: support, specific-question, reopen-closed

This is the post:
[Equivalent Binary Trees Exercise, achieving the "concurrency"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64468668/3912693)

I am requesting meta to reopen this question because I have posted it more than 70 days ago.

I undeleted and deleted the question because the commenters said that I should clarify the question. I edited it, but the question had been closed for the same reason as they said.

I then thought, "My question is poor to be posted and I have no time to improve the question" Thus I decided to just delete it.

I was too ignorant about the rules of Stack Overflow, thinking that the *deletion* is for pretending the question have never existed

The question with unresolved close affected my reputation, and I have been banned from posting a new one. Thus I decided to undelete and improve it.

---

I clarified what is the problem I'm focusing on. Also, I have my own answer (yet still not rigid enough to be posted).

**Update**
The post got closed again for another reason, so I edited the question to contain more detail.

Comment: Please review the help center article [What if I disagree with the closure of a question? How can I reopen it?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reopen-questions)

Comment: @HereticMonkey
I have read that too. My question cannot be added to reopen-queue because it has been posted more than 70 days ago, so I decided to make a request here.

Comment: Feedback for your question: Remove the stuff about being from an assignement, do not mention Same (all irrelevant for question). Remove part about guessing what the author means (also irrelevant). Add an explanation of what the Walk function is actually supposed to do (because that's very unclear as of now). The question still reads as if most of your problem is about understanding what your teacher wants, but that's not going to fly. Focus on the implementation problem only. As of now, I would probably vote to leave the question closed.

Comment: @BDL
Thanks for your feedback. I want to make sure this is not an assignment, and there is no teacher. I'm solely walking through the Tour of Go. I will edit the post right away.

Comment: It has to be a mistake I omitted the link to the Tour of Go link. What a shame...

Comment: @BDL I updated the original question. I added a link to the original source, replaced the part about author's intention with comments saying it is self-challenge.
I didn't add details about the exercise requirements since other questions about Equivalent Binary Trees exercise didn't do so, like https://stackoverflow.com/q/12224042/3912693.

Comment: @Jinux That (the age of your question and its relation to why you're posting here) is something it would be good to add to this question. Giving as much information as possible as to why your question isn't the same as the hundreds of other "Reopen my question" requests posted on meta every week will help you.

Comment: @Jinux Welcome to Meta! Thank you for making an effort to get out of the question-ban and for not coming to meta just to "rant and complain". Here's my upvote. I hope others consider encouraging such effort and not downvote this question.

Comment: Unfortunately, the post has been closed again for another reason. I'm working hard to know what's insufficient.

Comment: @Jinux The only thing I could imagine is that it still lacks a bit in the explanation of what the Walk function is supposed to do. I wouldn't close it for that reason, but I can understand that other see it differently.

Comment: @BDL Do you mean what it lacks is my own requirement, not the requirement stated in the original exercise?

Comment: I mean that it lacks the explanation of the original exercise. Its unclear what the functionality of Walk is. Is it a pre-order traversal of the tree? What is the expected output?

Comment: I thought “A Tour of Go” is famous enough in the Go community that I could omit detail of the exercise. If your guess is right, my thought was just mere speculation.

As stated in https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/7, it's a in-order traversal. The channel given to Walk call is expected to send values from in-order traversal.

Answer (score 2):

So that this meta-question has an answer, I am  noting that the subject question has now been re-opened as shown in the [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64468668/timeline).

Comment: And has since been re-closed

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels And has since been re-reopened. :-)

Comment: @AdrianMole: I'm getting dizzy with all this